# Deserialize JSON to POJO using Retrofit and Gson

Tags: java, json, gson, retrofit, json-deserialization

I am working with an API that responds like the following for a single user resource:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": 11,
    "first_name": "First",
    "last_name": "Last",
    "books": {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": 13,
          "name": "Halo"
        }
      ]
    },
    "games": {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Halo"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

or like the following for multiple user resources:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 11,
      "first_name": "First",
      "last_name": "Last",
      "books": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": 13,
            "name": "Halo"
          }
        ]
      },
      "games": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Halo"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
  ],
  "meta": {
    "pagination": {
      "total": 11,
      "count": 10,
      "per_page": 10,
      "current_page": 1,
      "total_pages": 2,
      "links": {
        "next": "http://api.###.com/users?page=2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Key things to notice are:

1. all resources are nested under a `data` key, single as an object or multiple as an array of objects. This includes nested resources such as books and games in the example above.
2. I need to be able retrieve the values of the `meta` key for my pagination routines

### User model

```
public class User extends BaseModel {

    public Integer id;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;

    public List<Book> books; // These will not receive the deserialized 
    public List<Game> games; // JSON due to the parent data key

}
```

### Custom JSON deserializer

```
public class ItemTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> type) {

        final TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
        final TypeAdapter<JsonElement> elementAdapter = gson.getAdapter(JsonElement.class);

        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {

            public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
                delegate.write(out, value);
            }

            public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {

                JsonElement jsonElement = elementAdapter.read(in);
                if (jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
                    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
                    // If the data key exists and is an object or array, unwrap it and return its contents
                    if (jsonObject.has("data") && (jsonObject.get("data").isJsonObject() || jsonObject.get("data").isJsonArray())) {
                        jsonElement = jsonObject.get("data");
                    }
                }

                return delegate.fromJsonTree(jsonElement);
            }
        }.nullSafe();
    }
}
```

This is all working fine but I can't figure out how to access the `meta` key for pagination.

Ideally I would get Gson to deserialize the response to the following POJO:

```
public class ApiResponse {
    public Object data;
    public Meta meta
}
```

and I could just cast the `response` field to the correct type in the response callback like the following:

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("include", "books,games");
ApiClient.getClient().authenticatedUser(params, new ApiClientCallback<ApiResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void failure(RestError restError) {
        Log.d("TAG", restError.message);
    }

    @Override
    public void success(ApiResponse response, Response rawResponse) {
        User user = (User) response.data; // Cast data field to User type
        Log.d("TAG", user.firstName);
        Log.d("TAG", "Total pages" + response.meta.pagination.total.toString()); // Still have access to meta key data
    }
});
```

However the `data` field of the `ApiResponse` object is `null`.

My Java is very rusty and I have no idea if this is even possible nor do I understand how to go about it correctly, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I needed the same thing and have managed to get it working by adding an `if` statement to your custom serializer:

```
…
    // If the meta key exists, consider the element to be root and don't unwrap it
    if (!jsonObject.has("meta")) {
        // If the data key exists and is an object or array, unwrap it and return its contents
        if (jsonObject.has("data") && (jsonObject.get("data").isJsonObject() || jsonObject.get("data").isJsonArray())) {
            jsonElement = jsonObject.get("data");
        }
    }
…
```

The reason why the `data` field of your `ApiResponse` was `null` is because your original deserializer was processing the whole response and making you "loose" the root object's `data` and `meta` elements.

I've also parametized the `ApiResponse` class:

```
public class ApiResponse<T> {
    public Meta meta;
    public T data;
}
```

That way deserializing still works without creating many different Response classes, while casting isn't needed anymore and you can specify the type of `ApiResponse`'s `data` field as needed (eg. `ApiResponse<User>` for single user resource, `ApiResponse<List<User>>` for multiple user resources, etc.).